# Android: how to sync layout and layout-land

Tags: android

In my Android app I have now a `main.xml` for `res/layout` and `res/layout-land`. I have done the design for the portrait layout, now I like to share a button between the portrait and the landscape layout.

How do I do this? I haven't found a clear guide on how to do this. I know Xcode for iOS development handles this, so how does Android Studio does this?

Comment: Simply copy the layout to `layout-port` (rename `layout`). The Views should have the very same names, to save yourself from big headaches later.

Comment: i think your question is, how to switch between portrait and landscape mode programmatically?

Comment: @Shivanshsaini Well, I think so. I would like to have the same button from layout portrait in the layout landscape, so they are like the same in `MainActivity.java`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put it into a separate XML file and then put it into your layout using `<include/>` or `<merge/>`. See [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) for more information.

Steps:

- Create a new **layout** (you should put your button `/layout/` since you are reusing it) file for your button and give it a name e.g. reusable_button.xml
- Put the code for your button inside
- Include that layout in the original layout file e.g. main_activity.xml by either using merge or include. Prefer the first one as it has better performance, since it does not add a new view hierarchy. I will use include for this example  `<include layout="@layout/reusable_button"/>`

Comment: Where would I place that XML file? I'm not too sure about the steps I have to take, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I have further elaborated.

Comment: In Android Studio, should I create a new `Layout resource file` and then also use `RelativeLayout` like in the other xml files?
What options should I choose in that screen after clicking Layout resource file?

Comment: I solved it, by using `New -> XML -> Layout file` with `RelativeLayout` as root tag.

Comment: Good, just don't go spamming with new ViewGroups like RelativeLayout for every reusable widget. Don't create a new ViewGroup if it is not necessary. As I said, you should prefer merge, there you don't need a RelativeLayout. Take a bit of time to read the link I provided you and it will become very clear to you :)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the best practice, I will remind myself to watch out for spamming ViewGroups. :)

Answer (score 0):

as you stated your problem, you want to toggle between potrait and landscape mode using a button.

so here you go

first make a button in both layout, give them same id

place this button in both xml layout and layout-land's xmls

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/change_orientation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="press me" />
```

and place this in your activity's oncreate method

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.change_orientation)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 2) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            } else {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            }
        }
    });
```

i hope this will help.